# Why the following code in Objective C cannot simulate 'message sent to deallocated instance '

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

```
char bytes[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4};
NSString * f = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:bytes length:4 encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

[f release];

NSLog(@"%@", [f description]); // Why no 'message sent to deallocated instance "?

[f release];
```

It only give me warning only, no crash..

```
Test1(26194,0xacf302c0) malloc: *** error for object 0x757c2f0: double free
```

Comment: you'll get the answer here stackoverflow.com/questions/13233853/why-can-i-send-messages-to-a-deallocated-instance-of-nsarray

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `NSString` is weird. (It's a class cluster, and it's toll-free-bridged to `CFString`.)

Try the same thing with a more ordinary object (like `NSObject`, for the simplest possible case) and you'll see things behaving more as expected. (But note that you will probably not get a "message sent to deallocated instance" error at all unless you enable guard malloc or a similar debug option.)

Answer (score 0):

You are releasing the object and then fetching its value, how can you send a message to an object which doesn't exists ;Use this

```
char bytes[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4};
 NSString * f = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:bytes length:4 encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];


NSLog(@"%@", [f description]); // Why no 'message sent to deallocated instance "?

[f release];
```

Comment: I think you missed the point that the OP is deliberately trying to replicate an error.